# Multiple queries for multiple input files

Tags: python, file

I have developed a code to "capture" in several input .txt files those lines with a especific query, but now I would like to find several queries. For instance "find: AA or CD or BC" in the input file.

I have not found any way to do so. Any suggestion would be so helpful!

Input file

```
AA
AB
AC
CD
CD
AA
BC
```

Output file

```
AA
CD
CD
AA
BC
```

This is the code I am using now:

```
import fileinput
from collections import deque
output_file = 'output.txt' 
buscado = 'AA'

contexto = deque([], 4)  # for keeping the last 4 lines


with open(output_file, "w") as f_out:
    for line in fileinput.input(files=["input.txt", "input2.txt"]):
        contexto.append(line)       
        if len(contexto) < 4:      
            continue
        if buscado in contexto[1]:  
            f_out.writelines(contexto)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
output_list = []
with open('data.txt', 'rt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    if line.strip('\n') in ("AA", "CD", "BC"):
        output_list.append(line.strip('\n'))
print(output_list)
```

**Output :**

```
['AA', 'CD', 'CD', 'AA', 'BC']
```

**[EDIT] Using fileinput**

If you want to use fileinput module to parse multiple files and to know in each file what keys are found it you can try like this :

```
import fileinput
 
with fileinput.FileInput(files=('data.txt', 'data1.txt'), mode='r') as input:
    for idx, line in enumerate(input):
        if input.isfirstline() == True:
            # Indicate the file name
            print(f'Reading file : {input.filename()}')
        if line.strip('\n') in ("AA", "CD", "BC"):
            print(line.strip('\n'))
```

**Content of data.txt**

```
AA
AB
AC
CD
CD
AA
BC
```

and

**Content of data1.txt**

```
AA
AB
AC
CD
CD
AA
BC
AA
BB
DD
FF
BC
BC
```

**Output :**

```
Reading file : data.txt
AA
CD
CD
AA
BC
Reading file : data1.txt
AA
CD
CD
AA
BC
AA
BC
BC
```

Comment: But using this I can't analyze several files by the same script. Also, I lose the rest of the script.

Comment: check my update